# How to create custom folder in TFS 2015, parallel to Shared Queries folder and not under it

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is there a way to create custom Query folders similar to "Shared Queries" folder in TFS 2015 update 2. We are able to create sub folders under "Shared Queries", but unable to find a option to create one in parallel to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such option. You can only create sub-folders under My Queries folder or Shared Queries folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going to the webportaal and then your project. Go to work and then to queries. Wait till the page is completely loaded. Then right mouse click on Shared Queries and press 'New query folder'.

**Edit**
Sorry, just didn't read the question completely. But what you are asking is not possible. The 2 main folders are there just to split the queries that you want to share and those who you want to keep private.

Comment: Thanks for the reply